# log4j2 - Need help setting up a JMS Appender to work with IBM MQ Series

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, log4j2

I'm having a hard time trying to find useful information and examples for using a log4j2 JMS appender to log XML message to an IBM MQ Series queue.  It's been a while since I've used log4j and that was back before version 2.x came out.

In my log4j2.xml file, I have the following definition for the JMS appender:

```
<JMS name="jmsQueue"
     destinationBindingName="BLTCAuditDest"
     factoryName="com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory"
     providerURL="file:///C:\\JNDI-Directory"
     factoryBindingName="com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsQueueConnectionFactory">
  <PatternLayout pattern="%m"/>
</JMS>
```

I created a .bindings file, that's in my C:\JNDI-Directory folder, using IBM MQ Explorer to create an Initial Context under the JMS Administered Objects folder.  The "BLTCAuditDest" is the name of the Destination I created that's in the C:\JNDI-Directory.bindings file.  And I'm guessing the IBM JmsQueueConnectionFactory is the proper class to use for the factoryBindingName.  However, with these settings I get the following error:

ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender jmsQueue org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error sending to JMS Manager 'jmsQueue': JMS message producer not available

So I'm not sure if my destinationBindingName and factoryBindingName are correct, but I'm not sure what values I should be using here.

Does anyone have a simple sample or have a link to a simple sample that would show how to use a JMS Appender with IBM MQ?

Thank you!

Comment: Which application server are you using?

Comment: I'm using WebSphere Application Server 9 on my local machine.  I'm doing my development in Rational Application Developer.

Comment: The `factoryBindingName` should not be the class name, it should be the logical name in the JNDI directory, e.g. when the bindings definition is like `def qcf(theFactory) ...`, then the `factoryBindingName` must be `theFactory`.

Comment: Thank you Daniel.  Through trial and error, and reading documentation on MQ Explorer, I was able to figure that out.  Now the issue I have is figuring out how to bundle the .bindings file with my WAR or EAR and have RefFSContextFactory find it.  I created a properties folder and added it to the classpath in the Manifest, but on my Windows development box, file:/properties/ is translated to C:\properties.  Is it possible for the providerURL to reference a file that's part of a JAR, WAR, or EAR?  Thx!

Comment: Instead of using a file-based JNDI context, I would try to configure the [Connection Factory](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tmj_adm25.html) and the [Queue](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tmj_adm27.html) directly in WebSphere Application Server.

Comment: That is an option.  However, I was hoping I could treat the .bindings file like any other properties file and keep it inside my JAR that's inside my EAR.  This way, I can reduce the amount of requests to our WAS admins when dealing with this .bindings or any other configuration.  I may just do the easiest thing and have our WAS admins put the .bindings file in some directory and reference the file path to it.

Comment: Not so sure if it is a good idea to mix the MQ jars that probably provide in your EAR with the MQ jars that are already already available by default in the WAS. But you can try it.